# Digital Ocean nginx server can be accessed via IP address but not custom domain name

Tags: node.js, nginx, dns, ip, digital-ocean

I am trying to setup my server on digital ocean. I am able to connect to the server by typing the ip address in the browser search box but doing same for the domain name does not work. I thought initially that the digital ocean droplet was not linked well with my namecheap domain but checking from https://whois.domaintools.com/ it seems to be linked properly

[image: whois details]

On digital ocean I have added `A`, `@` and `CNAME` recoreds

[image: Digital ocean panel details]

Also this below is my configurations for nginx.

[image]

I'll be glad if anyone can point me in the right direction or show me if I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Apparently I was redirecting all traffic from http to https while the https was not setup. adding an SSL certificate, in my case with let's encrypt fixes the issue.